# How to iterate over an array of SVG elements, and for each SVG element, get the value of a particular property?

Tags: javascript, svg

```
const iconsArray = [<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title>c info 24</title><g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="" stroke-linejoin="round"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11"></circle><line x1="12" y1="11" x2="12" y2="17" stroke=""></line><circle cx="12" cy="7" r="1" stroke="" fill="#000000"></circle></g></svg>]
```

I want to loop through this array, and get the `title` value of each `svg`.

`iconsArray[0]` returns:

```
{$flags$: 0, $tag$: 'svg', $text$: null, $elm$: null, $children$: Array(2), …}
$attrs$: {xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', height: '24', width: '24', viewBox: '0 0 24 24'}
$children$: (2) [{…}, {…}]
$elm$: null
$flags$: 0
$tag$: "svg"
$text$: null
```

There're two elements inside the `$children$` array. `g` and `title`. I want to get the value of `title`.

`iconsArray[0].querySelector("title")` returns `iconsArray[0].querySelector is not a function`.
`iconsArray[0].getElementsByTagName("*")` returns `iconsArray[0].getElementsByTagName is not a function`.
`iconsArray[0].children` returns `undefined`

Any ideas?

Comment: iconsArray is not a valid array btw, and the querySelector isn't related to constraints, it's targeting the css selector elements, so you need to show your original code which returns the the logged array result in your post, to find the right answer

Comment: I showed you the original code. By `return` I meant consoles out.

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman The issue could be related to the fact that I am using Stencil.js, and the `iconsArray` is a `@State`. `@State() iconsArray: SVGAElement[] = [.. ]`.

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman Perhaps the type of the array that I have specified, `SVGAElement` is wrong?

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman No, it's not the issue, because I tried `any` and it's still behaving the same way.

Comment: @ILoveCoffee the issue is definitely related to Stencil @State, it wraps the original array. I checked the Stencil docs but I don't see how to unwrap @State to a raw value. Maybe try `structuredClone` to convert the (presumably) Proxy instance to a normal value?

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Please add a `stencil.js` tag to your question - and ideally mention stencil in your title as well)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it yesterday. I already figured it out. You just have to use the brackets to access the properties, like this - `['$children$']`.